# "don't do this is if that command failed (or fails)"

Tags: grammar

"don't do this is if that command failed  "

or should I say

"don't do this is if that command  fails"
which way is grammatical correct?

Comment: One suggests that for whatever the command does, that action has not yet finished (fails) and the other suggests it is in progress (failed).

Comment: Neither is correct at present: Why have you included *is*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Don't do A if command B failed/fails.

They are both grammatically correct.